# TikZ: positioning library with multiplier

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm using the `positioning` library in TikZ to places nodes. Is it possible to have some kind of multiplier applied to a placement, for example, something like `(above=of C)*2`?

Minimum example with an error in node D (where I tried something that didn't work):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,
    entity/.style={
        draw, rectangle,
        minimum size=1cm, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
    }
]
    \node (C) {};
    \node (A) [entity, above left=of C] {A};
    \node (B) [entity, above right=of C] {B};
    \node (D) [entity, ($(above=of C) * 2$)] {D};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

<sub>Note: Usually I specifying the position of nodes with coordinates but was curious about using the positioning library.</sub>

Comment: Does `above=2 of C` fail for you?

Comment: @TeXnician -- That works! ty